# Compare characters in string in java?

Tags: java, string, collections

My task is to  removes the consecutively repeating characters and replaces the count of the repeated characters in the string. When I compared the two characters, I got the IndexOutOfBoundException. I dont know how to rectify it. Am beginner. I attached my code here. Could anyone verify my code and help me.

program:

```
import java.util.*;
public class RemoveDupchar{

     public static void main(String []args){

        String string = "aabbccdefatafazaacddsegf";

   char[] chars = string.toCharArray();

   ArrayList<Character> al=new ArrayList<Character>();
     for(char c :  chars)
     {
         al.add(c);
     }

     int i=0;

     int j=0,k=1;
     char[] r = new char[100];

     for(i=0;i<al.size();i++)
     {
         char ch;
         ch=al.get(i);
         if(ch!=al.get(i+1))      **//I got Runtime error here**
         {
             r[j++]=ch;
         }
         else
         {
             r[j++]=ch;
             while(al.get(i)==ch)
             {
                 ++k;
                 ++i;
             }
             r[j++]=(char)k;
         }
     }

     for(char c: r)
     {
         System.out.print(c);
     }
}
```

}

Comment: Exact stacktrace please, we need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, collections are 0 based, thus, a collection of size 5 will have locations from 0 to 4. In your case, you have this line: `al.get(i+1)`. This will attempt to access the `n + 1`th location, where `n` is the size of the collection.

Replacing `for(i=0;i<al.size();i++)` with this: `for(i=0;i<al.size() - 1;i++)` should solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the output.

Comment: I want to add the count values in a character array. But I cant add it in character array. The problem is in the line r[j++]=char(k). How do I add integer value to char array.

Comment: @user3661367: An `int` in a character array will be treated as a character. What you could do would be to have a string array instead and add the string value of the character and number to it instead.

Comment: K.. I will try now.